# How can I turn an inputed string into a list in python?

Tags: python

How can I have a user enter a string and then have that string made into a list? I have tried the following code:

```
    original=input("Enter message to encode: ")
    originallist = list(original)
    print originallist
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
    NameError: name 'Whatever I input' is not defined
```

Comment: python 2 or python 3 ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal Notice the lack of parentheses. A sure sign of Python 2.x

Comment: `originallist = list(raw_input("Enter message to encode: "))` would work perfect in case of Python 2.x

Comment: A list of characters? A list of words? A list of lengths of each word?

Comment: `originallist = list(raw_input("Enter message to encode: "))` breaks it down into a list of characters.  This probably isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: Each of the answers so far either starts with an assumption or makes multiple guesses. This question needs a more specific description of the task.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This question does need more information `'Whatever I input'` is only mentioned in the error, not any of the code he posted.

Comment: That part is presumably what was entered at the `input()` prompt, causing the error. The desired behavior, however, is still undetermined.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly what you mean, but if you want the whole string put inside a list, then you could do:

```
a = list(raw_input())
```

OR

```
a = [raw_input()]
# `split()` can take an argument — the character (or string) at which to split
# i.e.: "Jim and Tim; Bob and Rob".split(";") -> ["Jim and Tim", "Bob and Rob"]
```

If you wanted the string split up into tokens, then you could use the built-in `split` method.

```
a = raw_input().split()
```

NOTE: Of course, for Python 3, `raw_input()` would be replaced with `input()`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `input` in python 2. Try `raw_input` instead:

```
original=raw_input("Enter message to encode: ")
originallist = list(original)
print originallist 
# OR try these alternative ways of splitting:
print original.split(' ')
print original.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using a delimiting character in your input string (such as `,`), you would do it like:

```
>>> original = raw_input('Enter message to encode: ')
Enter message to encode: foo,bar,baz
>>> print original
foo,bar,baz
>>> my_list = original.split(',')  # Replace `,` with your actual delimiter.
>>> assert my_list == ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>>
```

Note the use of `split()` rather than `list()`.